# Plot overlapping rectangles

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization, heatmap

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
x, y, width, height
10,20,30,30
11,25,35,30
```

Is there any way to create in R a simple heatmap of the rectangular area?
Just like following image (or something similar):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ggplot2` package and `geom_rect` layer (specify cornes with `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(xmin = x, xmax = x + width,
                 ymin = y, ymax = y + height)) +
    geom_rect(color = NA, fill = "grey", alpha = 0.4) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"))
```

[image]